# Java mouse events are not captured by JOGL

Tags: java, jogl

I want to write a program by Java and Jogl. We have a Jframe and a GLJPanel which resides inside that frame. The program receives mouse events and when the user clicks on the frame it draws a point on that position. I wrote the following code for this program but there is problem. Sometime when you click on the frame the event for that click is not issued or is issued with delay. Please tell me how to fix this.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package jogli;

import com.jogamp.opengl.util.FPSAnimator;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.media.opengl.awt.GLJPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 *
 * @author HESSAM
 */
public class JOGLI extends JFrame {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    private GLJPanel pan;

    public JOGLI()
    {
        pan = new Curve();
        this.setMinimumSize( new Dimension( 800 , 600 ) );
        this.add(pan);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
        final FPSAnimator anime1 = new FPSAnimator( pan , 24 , true ); 
        anime1.start();
        this.addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                // Use a dedicate thread to run the stop() to ensure that the
                // animator stops before program exits.
                new Thread() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                      if (anime1.isStarted()) {
                           anime1.stop();
                       }                      
                      System.exit(0);
                   }
                }.start();         
            }
        });                                
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JOGLI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        // TODO code application logic here
    }
}




/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package jogli;

import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.media.opengl.GL2;
import javax.media.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
import javax.media.opengl.GLEventListener;
import javax.media.opengl.awt.GLJPanel;

/**
 *
 * @author HESSAM
 */
public class Curve extends GLJPanel implements GLEventListener {
    private ArrayList < int[] > pointSet;
    private GL2 mygl;
    public Curve()
    {        
        pointSet = new ArrayList<>();
        this.addGLEventListener(this);
        this.addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked( MouseEvent e )
            {
                final int[] newPoint = { 0 , 0 , 0 };
                newPoint[0] = e.getX();
                newPoint[1] = getSize().height - e.getY();                                
                pointSet.add(newPoint);
                display();

            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) { 
        mygl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
        mygl.glClearColor(0.15f, 0.15f , 0.15f , 1);
        mygl.glClear(mygl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        mygl.glLoadIdentity();
        mygl.glMatrixMode(mygl.GL_PROJECTION);
        mygl.glLoadIdentity();
        mygl.glOrtho(0, getSize().width, 0, getSize().height, -1, 1);
        mygl.glMatrixMode(mygl.GL_MODELVIEW);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {        
    }

    @Override
    public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) { 
        mygl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
        mygl.glClear(mygl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        mygl.glBegin(mygl.GL_POINTS);
        {
            mygl.glColor3d(1, 0.1, 0.5);
            for( int i = 0 ; i < pointSet.size() ; ++i )
            {
                for(int j = -2 ; j <= 2 ; ++j ) {
                    for(int k = -2 ; k <= 2 ; ++k ) {
                        mygl.glVertex2d(pointSet.get(i)[0] + j, pointSet.get(i)[1] + k);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        mygl.glEnd();
    }

    @Override
    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width, int height) {        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AWT input EventDispatchThread gets blocked by rendering and vice versa, this is a design limitation by AWT since it perform input and rendering on a single thread.

The recommendation is to use the JogAmp JOGL NEWT input and windowing system.
NEWT is designed to do input in parallel to rendering. You may use a GLWindow (NEWT) directly or use a NewtCanvasAWT (GLWindow inside a AWT application) and then use a NEWTEventFiFo to inject input into the rendering loop. 
http://jogamp.org/jogl/doc/NEWT-Overview.html